# What are the ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter.filter() Arguments?

Tags: python, opencv, disparity-mapping

I get a `ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter` from `cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher)`,
but I cannot get `ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter.filter()` to work.

The error I get is

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!disparity_map_right.empty() && (disparity_map_right.depth() == CV_16S) && (disparity_map_right.channels() == 1)) in cv::ximgproc::DisparityWLSFilterImpl::filter, file ......\opencv_contrib\modules\ximgproc\src\disparity_filters.cpp, line 262

In general, how do I figure out how to use this, when there isn't a single google result for "ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter"?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue too, what you need to do is create the filter first. Then you can filter... hopefully that makes sense. Here is a code snippet of what I used tested on Python 3.6 opencv3.4.2

```
wls = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(left_Matcher)
filteredDisp = wls.filter(leftStereoComputeOutput, leftOriginalImage, disparity_map_right=rightStereoComputeOutput)
```

In order to figure out how this bit worked, I had to look at the documentation and at what other people had implemented on Github, then connect the pieces. Lots of Trial and Error.

Arguments for the filter are:

```
Python:
filtered_disparity_map  =   cv.ximgproc_DisparityFilter.filter( disparity_map_left, left_view[, filtered_disparity_map[, disparity_map_right[, ROI[, right_view]]]] )
```

Parameters:

**disparity_map_left**  disparity map of the left view, 1 channel, CV_16S type. Implicitly assumes that disparity values are scaled by 16 (one-pixel disparity corresponds to the value of 16 in the disparity map). Disparity map can have any resolution, it will be automatically resized to fit left_view resolution.

**left_view**   left view of the original stereo-pair to guide the filtering process, 8-bit single-channel or three-channel image.

**filtered_disparity_map**  output disparity map.

**disparity_map_right** optional argument, some implementations might also use the disparity map of the right view to compute confidence maps, for instance.

**ROI** region of the disparity map to filter. Optional, usually it should be set automatically.

**right_view**  optional argument, some implementations might also use the right view of the original stereo-pair.

The above Parameters were found at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d72/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1DisparityFilter.html

Comment: Where do I get `rightStereoComputeOutput`? SGBM and SBM return only the left disparity.

Comment: What is `left_matcher`? I have been looking through the docs and can't quite figure that part out.

Comment: Hey Matt and jiggy, I'm going to update my answer with some code so that you have some context

Comment: Well I was going to, but it seems like I'm having a heck of a time finding this specific piece. To each of your questions (from the best of my knowledge):

jiggy - the rightStereoComputeOutput was just a variable I named for the disparity_map_right optional argument. It is calculated similarly to the how you got the disparity_map_left except that you flip the photos.

Matt - I wish I had the codebase in front of me, but I can't remember for the life of me what that was apologies

Answer (score 0):

Unlike c++, Python doesn't work well with pointers. So the arguments are

Filtered_disp = ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter.filter(left_disp,left, None,right_disp)

Note that it's no longer a void function in Python!

I figured this out through trial and error though.