# How do you use OpenCV's DisparityWLSFilter in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, disparity-mapping

I can compute a depth map with `cv2.StereoSGBM` that looks pretty good. Now I want to apply WLS filtering as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276962/what-are-the-ximgproc-disparitywlsfilter-filter-arguments) answer has some info, which I follow below, but I can't quite get to work.

How do I use `ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter` in Python? I know the theory and how to do it in C++, but can't find any documentation for how the functions were wrapped in Python. (Using OpenCV 4.2.0). [This](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/src/disparity_filters.cpp) is the source on GitHub, but it doesn't contain the Python bindings either.

Doing:

```
wls = cv2.ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter.filter(disparity_SGBM, imgL)
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\stereo_SGBM_filtering.py", line 158, in <module>
    wls = cv2.ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter.filter(disparity_SGBM, imgL)
TypeError: descriptor 'filter' requires a 'cv2.ximgproc_DisparityFilter' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So I know I'm at least able to access the functions.

Fixing it like this:

```
wls = cv2.ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter(stereoSGBM)
filtered_disparity_map = wls.filter(disparity_SGBM, imgL)
```

Doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't give me an image.

Full details:

Original images (`Tsukuba` from the  [Middlebury data set](https://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/)).

[image]
[image]

My depth map looks like this:

[image]

```
import cv2 

imgL = cv2.imread("tsukuba_l.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # left image

... 

win_size = 2
min_disp = -4
max_disp = 9
num_disp = max_disp - min_disp  # Needs to be divisible by 16
stereoSGBM = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=min_disp,
    numDisparities=num_disp,
    blockSize=5,
    uniquenessRatio=5,
    speckleWindowSize=5,
    speckleRange=5,
    disp12MaxDiff=2,
    P1=8 * 3 * win_size ** 2,
    P2=32 * 3 * win_size ** 2,
)

disparity_SGBM = stereoSGBM.compute(imgL_undistorted, imgR_undistorted)
wls = cv2.ximgproc_DisparityWLSFilter(stereoSGBM)
filtered_disparity_map = wls.filter(disparity_SGBM, imgL)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [createDisparityWLSFilter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d17/group__ximgproc__filters.html#ga8a351f67b897bb7cdaccaef115bafcac) factory method to get an instance of DisparityWLSFilter and use it.

For example:

```
wsize=31
max_disp = 128
sigma = 1.5
lmbda = 8000.0
left_matcher = cv2.StereoBM_create(max_disp, wsize);
right_matcher = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher);
left_disp = left_matcher.compute(left_image, right_image);
right_disp = right_matcher.compute(right_image,left_image);

# Now create DisparityWLSFilter
wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher);
wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda);
wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma);
filtered_disp = wls_filter.filter(left_disp, left_image, disparity_map_right=right_disp);
```

Comment: What version of OpenCV is this for? Did you learn this from official python documentation? Where can I find that? I'm on version 4.1.1 and cv2 has no attribute ximgproc

Comment: Can you also give an example of using WLS for guided filtering, e.g. using rgb image to guide the filtering of a depth map? (something like Fig 10 in http://kaiminghe.com/publications/pami12guidedfilter.pdf)

Comment: @ABlankenship: It took me a bit to figure out, but you have to install the package that comes with the extra OpenCV modules by doing `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.